# how to use own permissions and group models instead of auth_group and auth_permission (AbstractBaseUser style)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I need to made own permissions system (not only single permission!) based on groups.

But my groups and group_permissions are dynamicaly created from other tables so I would like to create `myapp_groupview` instead of `auth_group` and `myapp_group_permissions` instead of `auth_group_permissions`.

After 8h of searching, testing i found nothing... auth_group is still there and can't find method to get rid of it....

`AbstractBaseGroup` would be a such easy solution....

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, we didn't touch default permissions models and their instances since they do have a useful purpose (can limit admin panel available models). What we did is added to default_data dump a list of custom permissions and groups that were granted to a user (we did it in a form of a script that would check any new changes and add them on management command execution).

After custom permissions (like "can_see_shop_cart" or "can_edit_shop_cart") and groups (like "customer") were granted, you can check if user have it at the beginning of request like this:

```
Permission.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) | Q(group__user=request.user), codename="can_see_shop_cart").exists()
```

Also, you can make API, that lists every permission user has to limit frontend functionality depending on custom_permissions.